# React Native Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id )

Tags: react-native, api

I am getting an error like this:

> Possible unhandled promise rejection (id:0)

The number `id` is `+1` like every second time,
I don't know how to fix this or why does this happen
My project can run but there is a message at the bottom of Emulator said Possible unhandled promise rejection

And this is my code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Image, SafeAreaView, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import NumberFormat from 'react-number-format';


const covidURL = 'https://covid19.ddc.moph.go.th/api/Cases/today-cases-all'

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(covidURL)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((json) => setData(json))
            .catch((error) => alert(error))
            .finally(setLoading(false))
            
    })

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <Text style={styles.headerText}>Home</Text>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.headSection}>
                <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 24, }}>สถานการณ์ Covid-19</Text>
            </View>

            {isLoading ? (
                <ActivityIndicator />
            ) : (
                <FlatList
                    data={data}
                    keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        <View>
                            <View style={styles.covidHeader}>

                                <View style={styles.covidDetailLeft}>
                                    <Text style={styles.covidText}>ติดเชื้มเพิ่มวันนี้</Text>
                                    <NumberFormat
                                        value={item.new_case}
                                        displayType={'text'}
                                        thousandSeparator={true}
                                        prefix={'+ '}
                                        renderText={value => <Text style={styles.numberCovidText}>{value}</Text>} 
                                    />
                                </View>

                                <View style={styles.covidDetailRight}>
                                    <Text style={styles.covidText}>หายป่วยวันนี้</Text>
                                    <NumberFormat
                                        value={item.new_recovered}
                                        displayType={'text'}
                                        thousandSeparator={true}
                                        prefix={'+ '}
                                        renderText={value => <Text style={styles.numberCovidText}>{value}</Text>} 
                                    />
                                </View>
                             
                            </View>

                            <View style={styles.covidHeader}>

                                <View style={styles.covidDetailLeft2}>
                                    <Text style={styles.covidText}>ติดเชื้อสะสม</Text>
                                    <NumberFormat
                                        value={item.total_case}
                                        displayType={'text'}
                                        thousandSeparator={true}
                                        prefix={''}
                                        renderText={value => <Text style={styles.numberCovidText}>{value}</Text>} 
                                    />
                                </View>

                                <View style={styles.covidDetailRight2}>
                                    <Text style={styles.covidText}>หายป่วยสะสม</Text>
                                    <NumberFormat
                                        value={item.total_recovered}
                                        displayType={'text'}
                                        thousandSeparator={true}
                                        prefix={''}
                                        renderText={value => <Text style={styles.numberCovidText}>{value}</Text>} 
                                    />
                                </View>

                            </View>

                            <View style={styles.covidHeader}>

                                <View style={styles.covidDetailLeft3}>
                                    <Text style={styles.covidText}>เสียชีวิตเพิ่ม</Text>
                                    <NumberFormat
                                        value={item.new_death}
                                        displayType={'text'}
                                        thousandSeparator={true}
                                        prefix={'+ '}
                                        renderText={value => <Text style={styles.numberCovidText}>{value}</Text>} 
                                    />
                                </View>

                                <View style={styles.covidDetailRight3}>
                                    <Text style={styles.covidText}>เสียชีวิตสะสม</Text>
                                    <NumberFormat
                                        value={item.total_death}
                                        displayType={'text'}
                                        thousandSeparator={true}
                                        prefix={'+ '}
                                        renderText={value => <Text style={styles.numberCovidText}>{value}</Text>} 
                                    />
                                </View>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    )}
                />)}
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your `covidURL` is correct or in your `FlatList`, try to replace your `KeyExtractor` prop with `keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}`.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: I try it but nothing change.

Comment: then make sure if your URL is working fine

Comment: yeah covidURL is working, and i try another url but there is a same problem

Comment: did you tried to use the `FlatList` component of `react native`?

Comment: i have tried but it didn't work